# setTimeout triggering instantly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The zfade is triggering instantly - any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$('.country_holder').hover(
          function(zfade) { 
                  $('.gallery_img').css('z-index','999'); 
          },
          function() {
                  $('.gallery_img').css('z-index','99'); 
          });

  setTimeout(zfade, 10000);
```

Edit to include CSS/html.

Jsfiddle shorthand: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkz4sef/

Jsfiddle longhand: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkz4sef/2/

Comment: Where is `zfade` defined?

Comment: provide all the code and html

Comment: Ah, I had somehow confused myself and thought I could define it inside the function's brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function before you use it

```
var zfadeIn = function() { 
    $('.gallery_img').css('z-index','999'); 
};
var zfadeOut = function() {
    $('.gallery_img').css('z-index','99'); 
};

$('.country_holder').hover(zfadeIn,zfadeOut);

setTimeout(zfadeIn, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful - but I still can't get the zfadeIn to trigger after 10000ms, it happens instantly. There is no other code relating to this function.

Comment: Np. Add an alert('just runned'); in the zfadeIn function. Does it display the alert directly?

Comment: displays, but instantly. I just tried removing all other js code & it is behaving identically. also tried to define it using "function zfadeIn ()...."

Comment: try it this way then: setTimeout(function(){ zfadeIn(); alert('fired'); }, 10000);

Comment: alert works, zfadeIn still runs instantly

Comment: in fact I realise it fires regardless of whether I hover over the correct div

Comment: managed to find a much each solution using pointer-events:none; !